# Where do the "plague comparison" paragraphs in the Hagadah come from?

Tags: sources-mekorot, passover-seder-hagada

In [the Hagadah](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=10664&st=&pgnum=35) after enumerating the plagues, there are 3 paragraphs deriving the number of plagues in Egypt and at the Sea of Reeds - by Rabbi Yosi Haglili, Rabbi Eliezer and Rabbi Akiva.

What's the original source of these? I couldn't find it in a Gemarah. Is it in a *Tosefta*, maybe?

Comment: I have seen a reference to the  Mekhilta d’Rashbi and other references that say it is a mishna (since the Rabbis referred to were Amoraim), but I have not yet seen a specific citation.

Comment: In general the Haggadah draws greatly from Mechilta d’Rashbi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be based on [this piece](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mekhilta_DeRabbi_Shimon_Bar_Yochai.14.29?with=all&lang=he) in Mekhilta deRashbi, Parshat Beshalach (Shemot 14:29).

Comment: Thanks. The link is blocked, now, so IY"H, I'll look later. No wonder I had trouble finding it.